# Importing the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace

Tags: asp.net, iis, excel-automation

I need to use excel automation in my ASP.NET web app. I am trying to import it in a .aspx file using the following code: 
`<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" %>` however, when I open the page in the browser I get the error `The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'`. So I assume I have to add some library to my project. I am using IIS 7.5 to create this web app, not Visual Studio. So is there a way to import external libraries into my ASP.NET project in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Reference -  .Net tab - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Excel 2010 use version 14 / Excel 2007 use version 12

click ok.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drop the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll into the `bin` directory. If that doesn't work try adding it to the `<assemblies>` in your `web.config` file.

[Assemblies in Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944536/assemblies-in-web-config)

Comment: Thank you! Where would I find the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll file though?